# LAZY relationship instantiation issue in Glassfish

Tags: jpa, ejb, glassfish-3

I have Glassfish 3.1 and I got oneToMany relationship. Keep getting error:

```
Exception Description: An attempt was made to traverse a relationship using indirection that had a null Session. This often occurs when a n entity with an uninstantiated LAZY relationship is serialized and that lazy relationship is traversed after serialization. To avoid this issue, ins tantiate the LAZY relationship prior to serialization.
```

User Entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
public class User implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8636046618352460140L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long userId;
    private String userName;
    private int userAge;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    public User() {

    }

// getters & setters
}
```

Group Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS_GROUPS")
public class Group implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9124043819358665396L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long groupId;
    private String groupName;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="JOIN_USER_GROUP",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="groupId")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="userId")})
    private List<User> users = null;

    public Group() {

    }
// getters & setters
}
```

And the bean:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
    ...
public Group searchGroup(String groupName) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT g FROM Group g " +
            "WHERE g.groupName = :name");
    q.setParameter("name", groupName);
    Group result = (Group) q.getResultList().get(0);
    result.getUsers().size(); // << LAZY instantiation
    return result;
}
// NOT TESTED
public void updateGroup(Group group) 
{
    em.merge(group);
}

    ...
```

Client test driver:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try
    {
        Context jndi = new InitialContext();

        GroupManagementService service = (GroupManagementService)
                  jndi.lookup("java:global/GroupsManagement/GroupManagementServiceImp");

        User u = new User("John", 20, 54.04, 0.4);

                    // the group home is already in a database
        Group group = service.searchGroup("home");

                    group.getUsers().add(u); // << ERROR here
                    service.updateGroup(group);

                    /* IF do this */
        List<User> l = group.getUsers();
        if(l == null)
            System.out.println("NULL");
        else {
            System.out.println("SIZE: "+l.size()); // << ERROR here

        }

                    ...
```

Any suggestions about the code? 
Similar questions posted on the forum, unfortunately does not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

The call to group.getUsers() is causing this exception to be thrown because the User List was never populated in the JPA Session. The lazy relationships must be traversed before exiting the scope of the JPA Session to avoid the Exception.

In many cases, simply calling size() on your lazily loaded list within the JPA Session will resolve the Exception.

```
public Group searchGroup(String groupName) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT g FROM Group g " +
        "WHERE g.groupName = :name");
    q.setParameter("name", groupName);
    Group result = (Group) q.getResultList().get(0);
    result.getUsers().size(); // << LAZY instantiation
    return result;
}
```

However, there are some cases where .size() by itself fails to resolve the problem. I have found it works when in combination with a JOIN FETCH when that occurs.

```
public Group searchGroup(String groupName) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT g FROM Group g LEFT JOIN FETCH g.users " +
        "WHERE g.groupName = :name");
    q.setParameter("name", groupName);
    Group result = (Group) q.getResultList().get(0);
    result.getUsers().size(); // << LAZY instantiation
    return result;
}
```

An alternative way to perform the JOIN FETCH:

```
public Group searchGroup(String groupName) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT g FROM Group g " +
        "WHERE g.groupName = :name");
    q.setParameter("name", groupName);
    q.setHint("eclipselink.left-join-fetch","g.users"); // << join fetch as hint
    Group result = (Group) q.getResultList().get(0);
    result.getUsers().size(); // << LAZY instantiation
    return result;
}
```

Comment: ok, i FIXED it. I deleted my ejb.jar file from Glassfish and deployed  a new one. 
I also added `service.updateGroup(group);` to `searchGroup` method. But, this does not make a difference as when i comment it application still works. 
HOW can you comment on this odd behavior?

Comment: made mistake in comment. I have edited `result.getUsers().size()`

Comment: I honestly don't see anything else in the code sample that would cause the Exception. The situation described in the answer and calling detach on an entity are the 2 most likely reasons for that particular exception, at least in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I made the fetch type EAGER, it was the only way I could figure out how to avoid the error:

```
@OneToMany(..., fetch=EAGER, mappedBy = "...")
```